# Error in updating UDF in Excel in non active sheets

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, updates

I have created some UDF to automate some calculus me and some coworkers use regularly. 
For the sake of simplicity I paste a MWE of what I have a problem with, my actual code is longer, but takes the same input, a range of cells with one of the dimensions being equal to one (so one line or one column)

```
Public Function Test(Donnees As Range)

Dim Nombre_Cellules, Temp As Double
Dim Format_Donnees As String

Temp = 0


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'                                                                                   '
'       Parametres utiles generaux                                                  '
'                                                                                   '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Nb_Lignes = Donnees.Rows.Count
Nb_Colonnes = Donnees.Columns.Count
Premiere_Ligne = Donnees.Row
Premiere_Colonne = Donnees.Column
Derniere_Ligne = Donnees.Row + Nb_Lignes - 1
Derniere_Colonne = Donnees.Column + Nb_Colonnes - 1



'On definit la frequence et la taille associee
If Nb_Lignes = 1 Then
    Format_Donnees = "Colonnes"
    Nombre_Cellules = Nb_Colonnes
End If
If Nb_Colonnes = 1 Then
    Format_Donnees = "Lignes"
    Nombre_Cellules = Nb_Lignes
End If


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'                                                                                   '
'       Verifications des parametres et messages d'erreurs                          '
'                                                                                   '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'On verifie que la plage renseignée est soit sur une seule ligne soit sur une seule colonne
If (Nb_Lignes <> 1 And Nb_Colonnes <> 1) Then
        MsgBox _
            "La plage de données considérée est incorrecte, il ne peut s'agir que " & vbNewLine & _
            Chr(149) & " de données sur une seule ligne ou " & vbNewLine & _
            Chr(149) & " de données sur une seule colonne" _
            , , "Parametres incorrects"
        Test = CVErr(xlErrRef)
        Exit Function
End If


'On verifie que toute la période qui sert au calcul contient bien des valeurs numériques et ne contient pas de valeurs vides
If Format_Donnees = "Lignes" Then
    For i = 0 To Nombre_Cellules - 1
        If Not IsNumeric(Cells(Premiere_Ligne + i, Premiere_Colonne).Value) Then
            MsgBox _
            "La plage de donnée considérée est incorrecte" & vbNewLine & _
            "Toutes les cellules nécessaires au calcul dans la colonne ne sont pas numériques" _
            , , "Parametres incorrects"
            Test = CVErr(xlErrRef)
            Exit Function
        End If
        If (Cells(Premiere_Ligne + i, Premiere_Colonne).Value = "") Then
            MsgBox _
            "La plage de donnée considérée est incorrecte" & vbNewLine & _
            "Une cellule de la colonne considérée est vide et semble avoir une valeur manquante" _
            , , "Parametres incorrects"
            Test = CVErr(xlErrRef)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End If
If Format_Donnees = "Colonnes" Then
    For i = 0 To Nombre_Cellules - 1
        If Not IsNumeric(Cells(Premiere_Ligne, Premiere_Colonne + i).Value) Then
            MsgBox _
            "La plage de donnée considérée est incorrecte" & vbNewLine & _
            "Toutes les cellules nécessaires au calcul dans la ligne ne sont pas numériques" _
            , , "Parametres incorrects"
            Test = CVErr(xlErrRef)
            Exit Function
        End If
        If (Cells(Premiere_Ligne, Premiere_Colonne + i).Value = "") Then
            MsgBox _
            "La plage de donnée considérée est incorrecte" & vbNewLine & _
            "Une cellule de la ligne considérée est vide et semble avoir une valeur manquante" _
            , , "Parametres incorrects"
            Test = CVErr(xlErrRef)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End If


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'                                                                                   '
'                           Calculs a proprement parler                             '
'                                                                                   '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''


If Format_Donnees = "Lignes" Then
    For i = 0 To Nombre_Cellules - 1
        Temp = Temp + Cells(Premiere_Ligne + i, Premiere_Colonne).Value
    Next
End If
If Format_Donnees = "Colonnes" Then
    For i = 0 To Nombre_Cellules - 1
        Temp = Temp + Cells(Premiere_Ligne, Premiere_Colonne + i).Value
    Next
End If

Test = Temp
End Function
```

So as I will not be the sole user of this function, I have tried to include several checks and error messages. 
One is to check if the range selected has any empty values and any non numerical value.

Now my functions work (at least they calculate the thing I want them to), but I have some troubles with how they update. 
Note that I have pushed against user preferences so that all the value used are included in the range passed in input.

One of the issues I have been able to reproduce with this code is that If I use this function on several sheets of one workbook (so one `Test()` in worksheet1, and one `Test()` in worksheet2, and for one reason try to update the whole workbook (e.g. via `Ctrl` + `alt` + `shift` + `F9`), then I will get one warning I have set up (`"Une cellule de la ligne considérée est vide et semble avoir une valeur manquante"`) in a non active sheet.

Can someone explain me one ?

Comment: What error and where? You might need to include sheet references.

Comment: Not a real error, but one of the check that I have put in place appears as false, but disappear when I go back in the cell and `Enter` the formula again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Cells() with no sheet qualification. This means that it refers to whatever the active sheet happens to be. So it won't work correctly unless all the calls to your UDF are on the currently active sheet

You need to change this to  Donnees.Cells( ) and change the Cell indexes to refer to the cells within Donnees rather than cells within the whole sheet

Comment: It now seems obvious once you said it. Thank you.